# How to check only my own typescript code with --strictNullChecks?

Tags: angular, typescript, null, strict

I've created an **@angular** (4.0.0) based library and I want to use the `--strictNullChecks` check from TypeScript 2.

However [@angular could not make](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15432) all the code following the `--strictNullChecks` check so I'm unable to compile my project because if this.

Is there a way that I can still check my own code with `--strictNullChecks` check ?

Create a separate `tsconfig.ts` file? Or something else?